# System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'SimpleJson.JsonArray' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary

Tags: c#, xunit

I am trying to deserialize https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=1
And check the number of comments returned from Json body. I am working in C#  Xunit,please help.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Using Newtonsoft.Json (you can install through NuGet) you can deserialize the Json and do whatever you want with the data.

First, create your Post class:

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

Then, deserialize:

```
const string json = @"[{
    'postId': 1,
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'id labore ex et quam laborum',
    'email': 'Eliseo@gardner.biz',
    'body': 'laudantium enim quasi est quidem magnam voluptate ipsam eos\ntempora quo necessitatibus\ndolor quam autem quasi\nreiciendis et nam sapiente accusantium'
}]";

var posts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Post>>(json);
var numberOfComments = posts.Count;
```

Comment: can you help me how to assert it in Xunit?